# Can I delete a message from a queue of ActiveMQ in c# code?

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue, nms

I want to set a unique guid for each message in message head, then if I want, I could delete a specific message if I want to. Is there any api in NMS could help me deleting the message? I am using ActiveMQ 5.9.0 and NMS 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although only if that destination has no active consumers.  You can do something like this:

```
    protected static void DeleteDestination()
    {
        IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(ReplaceEnvVar(connectionURI));

        using (Connection connection = factory.CreateConnection() as Connection)
        {
            using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
            {
                IQueue queue = session.GetQueue(testQueueName);
                try
                {
                    connection.DeleteDestination(queue);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Bish. I have two further questions. First, I want to delete message from queeu when there are still active consumers. Second , I think your code delete the whole queue , am I right? I want to delete some messages from the queue, not the whole destination ,and these messages are identified by their guid set by the sender.

Comment: Is it possible to call REST management api in c#? if the answer is yes, can I get an example ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Very much possible to perform individual delete from C# and NMS library directly without the REST API.

I'm using NMS 18.0 from NuGet in a C# project for our support and maintenance tool [Nodinite](https://nodinite.com) and this is the code from one of the many [monitoring agents](https://documentation.nodinite.com/Documentation/Monitoring), in this case for ActiveMQ. This code is used to remove individually selected messages.

This code removes 1 message (messageId) from Queue (queueName)

```
 internal static void  DeleteMessageFromQueue(ActiveMQOption activeMQOption, string queueName, string messageId)
    {
        IConnectionFactory factory = CreateConnectionFactory(activeMQOption);

        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge))
            {
                using (IDestination destination = session.GetQueue(queueName))
                {
                    using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination, $"JMSMessageID LIKE '%{messageId}%'"))
                    {
                        connection.Start();
                        var message = consumer.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
                        consumer.Close();
                        connection.Close();
                        if (message == null)
                        {
                            throw new Exception($"Message '{messageId}' not found on queue '{queueName}'");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }                
        }            
    }
```

Helper method to create the factory (using a simple model c# Class that you need to replace with your own code but example should be simple enough to follow)

```
    public static Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory CreateConnectionFactory(ActiveMQOption activeMQOption)
    {
        Uri connecturi = new Uri(activeMQOption.ConnectionString);
        Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory factory = new Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory(connecturi);
        if (activeMQOption.UseAuthentication)
        {
            factory.UserName = activeMQOption.User;
            factory.Password = activeMQOption.Password;
        }

        return factory;
    }
```